# Label caption jumping around when I toggle "Enabled"

Tags: ms-access, vba, event-handling

This is hopefully a simple issue, but I'm struggling to find a solution. I am designing a Microsoft Access form where the user can click a VBA-powered option button to toggle the Enabled property on and off for certain fields in the form. The toggling behaves as expected, here is an example with a toggle button called "ExtraRows" that toggles an extra address field called "C/o" ("C_o" in the code):

```
Private Sub ExtraRows_Click()
    Select Case ExtraRows
        Case True
            Me.C_o.Enabled = True
        Case False
            Me.C_o.Enabled = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

The problem is that the placement of the label caption jumps a few pixels up/down and left/right when the option button is clicked, while the content of the related text box stays in place. The difference is illustrated below.

Field is **disabled**: the label caption ("C/o") sits two pixels below "Content".
[image]

Field is **enabled**: the label caption sits one pixel above "Content":
[image]

I would like the caption to stay in the same place all the time. I have tried resizing the label box and playing around with properties for margins and padding as wells as various special effect properties. What am I missing?

Comment: Odd issue. Is the label associated with the field? I tend to place my labels and controls in a stacked layout to avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: Yes, it is related. Thanks for the tip. I started out with a layout but then I have moved the fields around. It makes sense to keep fields that are used seldom separate. Just to check I created a new form from the underlying table without changing the layout. The issue persists but I noticed that the caption moves in the direction of the alignment (top and left or top and right).

Comment: Turns out I was too fast when I said I hade played around with properties and margins. The issue is solved when I set all margins to zero for the label. Padding does not seem to affect this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. I was too fast when I said I had played around with margins and padding. The issue disappears when the respective margin (top and right in the example) are set to zero. So it turns out that the margin settings for labels (but not text boxes) behave differently depending on whether the enabled property is set to true of false. A bug?

(Note: I had not set any margins myself; this was the default behavior.)